# Fetch last three orders from a table

Tags: mysql

Consider a table with the following columns:

1. Customer Email ID
2. Payment Method (COD/ Netbanking/ CreditCard/ DebitCard)
3. Order ID
4. Order Creation Date
5. Order Status(Success/ Failed/ Cancelled)

How do I fetch the last three successful orders past 3 months for each customer from these table in SQL along with the relevant details?

Comment: see this article:https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit painful in MySQL.  Probably the simplest method is to use variables.

Your column names are not clear.  And you have some additional conditions, but this is the basic idea:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (@rn := if(@c = customerid, @rn + 1,
                        if(@c := customerid, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from t cross join
           (select @rn := 0, @c := '') params
      order by customerid, orderdate desc
     ) t
where rn <= 3;
```

You can add the additional `where` conditions to the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

I Hope this helps

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLENAME
WHERE OrderStatus='Success'
ORDER BY OrderCreationDate DESC
LIMIT 3;
```

Comment: This will return 3 rows, OP wants 3 rows *for each customer*